# AWS ECS Exec fails on shell access to ECS Fargate task (Unable to start shell: Failed to start pty: fork/exec C:/Program: no such file or directory)

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-ecs

I am attempting to gain shell level access from a windows machine to a Linux ECS Task in an AWS Fargate Cluster via the AWS CLI (v2.1.38) through aws-vault.

The redacted command I  am using is

> aws-vault exec ***my-profile*** -- aws ecs execute-command --cluster
> ***my-cluster-name*** --task ***my-task-id***  --interactive --command "/bin/sh"

but this fails with this output

```
The Session Manager plugin was installed successfully. Use the AWS CLI to start a session.
Starting session with SessionId: ecs-execute-command-0bc2d48dbb164e010
SessionId: ecs-execute-command-0bc2d48dbb164e010 :
----------ERROR-------
Unable to start shell: Failed to start pty: fork/exec C:/Program: no such file or directory
```

I can see that ECS Exec is enabled on this task because an aws describe shows the following.
[image]

It appears that its recognising the host is a windows machine and attempting to initialise based on a variable that is windows specific.

Is anyone able to suggest what I can do to resolve this.

Comment: I would have loved to use https://github.com/tedsmitt/ecsgo but its not available on windows yet.

Comment: I've been unable to get the ECS exec command to run from a Windows command prompt or a GitBash command prompt. If you switch over to an Ubuntu command prompt in WSL2 it will work fine.

Comment: Hi @MarkB Thanks for the input, that has worked a treat.

Answer (score 12):

Ran into the same error. Using `--command "bash"` worked for me on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I was using windows 7, I think without WSL (Windows 10+) or Linux (or Mac) it just doesn't work.  There's another suggestion explained here that's not worth the trouble:

[Cannot start an AWS ssm session on EC2 Amazon linux instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68700385/cannot-start-an-aws-ssm-session-on-ec2-amazon-linux-instance)

For me, I just used a Linux bastion inside AWS and it worked from there.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into a similar issue. Not all docker containers required bash.
Try using:

```
--command "sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a windows powershell to run this command worked for me